# Debugger fails with Syntax Error: Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I've browse the internet but still can't figure out

when debugging the ionic app appear the error
`Waiting for the debugger to disconnect Syntax Error: Unexpected token *`

it's similar to #613

I think it's the problem of `home.page.ts`

home.page.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
//set the type of google of google.maps.LatLNg 
declare var google:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  //catch id="map" in home.page.html
  @ViewChild('map') mapRef:ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ionicViewDidLoad(){
    this.showMap();
  }


    showMap(){
      const location = new google.maps.LatLNg(51.507351,-0.127758);

      //set the  map
      const options = {
        center:location,
        zoom:10
      }

      //show the map
      const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement,options)

      this.addMarker(location,map);

    }
    //addMarker on google map
    addMarker(position,map){
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        map
      })
    }

}
```

here is my `package.json`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-maps",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

p.s.the height of map element had been set to 100%

it should show a full screen google map, but the page is blank
however when I start debug in visual studio, it appears the error

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=27765 dist\out-tsc\src\app\home\home.page.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:27765/c3a687c8-17ef-4c95-a58f-57d2b7d63499
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
c:\Users\User\for_ionic\ionic-maps\dist\out-tsc\src\app\home\home.page.js:1
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Waiting for the debuggeSyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
r to disconnect...
```

Comment: The problem is associated with your settings in tsconfig file. Check if you have correct settings in it. For more details, please check this issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3629